# Youtube video 100% width and custom height

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube

I have on my website I want to add a video with the width 100% and the height something like 400px; I tried the following:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <iframe class="video" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/yCOY82UdFrw" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

But my video turns out like this: 
[click me pls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akhgx.png)

the inside isn't 100%.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix thi? I'd appreciate it.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: What happens if you increase width and height of iframe?

Comment: I need it to be the 400px height shouldn't that be possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember a percentage width or height must have a parent element with some sort of dimension explicitly declared. In this case it's:

`html, body {width:100%; height:100%;}`.

For the height, you can still be flexible and have your 400px by:

```
height: auto;
min-height: 400px;
```

#### SNIPPET

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <iframe class="video" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/yCOY82UdFrw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: The preview shows the video how i want it to be. when i play it the inside becomes small.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// By Chris Coyier & tweaked by Mathias Bynens

$(function() {

 // Find all YouTube videos
 var $allVideos = $("iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com']"),

     // The element that is fluid width
     $fluidEl = $("body");

 // Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
 $allVideos.each(function() {

  $(this)
   .data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)
   
   // and remove the hard coded width/height
   .removeAttr('height')
   .removeAttr('width');

 });

 // When the window is resized
 // (You'll probably want to debounce this)
 $(window).resize(function() {

  var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();
  
  // Resize all videos according to their own aspect ratio
  $allVideos.each(function() {

   var $el = $(this);
   $el
    .width(newWidth)
    .height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));

  });

 // Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load
 }).resize();

});
```

```html
<iframe width="1280" height="750" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/yCOY82UdFrw?rel=0&amp;hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: There's an error I cannot see if it's actually workin.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line of code

```
<iframe class="video" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/yCOY82UdFrw" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
</iframe>
```

with this:

```
<iframe class="video" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/yCOY82UdFrw" width="1200" height="720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
</iframe>
```

and let me know what happens?

Comment: Same thing as before

Answer (score 0):

Just add the width and height attribute for the iframe. Please see sample:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yourVideo" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```